# Not able to use sub-queries in select in a statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Issue at hand is the inability to use sub-queries in a select statement with the following desired output:

ActivityName Attended Inprogress Cancelled Registered

```
 - ProdA     8           3      1         2

 - ProdB    16           5      3         4
```

Here is a sample of my current code. Is there a way not no use sub-queries?

```
select  
    (select act.ActivityName
        from [dbo].[dimActivity] act
        WHERE act.Code in ('SJM-GTD-HMM-A01')
    ) ActivityName,
    (Select count( emp.ID) 
        FROM [dbo].[factAttempt] fact
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimActivity] act ON act.ID = fact.ActivityID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimUser] emp ON emp.ID = fact.UserID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimDate] dt ON fact.EndDtID = dt.DateID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimCompletionStatus] comp ON fact.CompletionStatusID = comp.ID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimAttendanceStatus] att ON fact.AttendanceStatusID = att.ID

        WHERE (act.Code in ('SJM-GTD-HMM-A01','SJM-GTD-HMM-MAN01','SJM-GTD-HMM-PRT01','SJM-GTD-HMM-LAS01'))
        and att.name like ('%Attend%') 
    ) Attended,
    (Select count( emp.ID) 
        FROM [dbo].[factAttempt] fact
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimActivity] act ON act.ID = fact.ActivityID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimUser] emp ON emp.ID = fact.UserID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimDate] dt ON fact.EndDtID = dt.DateID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimCompletionStatus] comp ON fact.CompletionStatusID = comp.ID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimAttendanceStatus] att ON fact.AttendanceStatusID = att.ID

        WHERE (act.Code in ('SJM-GTD-HMM-A01','SJM-GTD-HMM-MAN01','SJM-GTD-HMM-PRT01','SJM-GTD-HMM-LAS01'))
        and att.name like ('%Progress%') 
    ) Inprogess,
        (Select count( emp.ID) 
        FROM [dbo].[factAttempt] fact
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimActivity] act ON act.ID = fact.ActivityID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimUser] emp ON emp.ID = fact.UserID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimDate] dt ON fact.EndDtID = dt.DateID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimCompletionStatus] comp ON fact.CompletionStatusID = comp.ID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimAttendanceStatus] att ON fact.AttendanceStatusID = att.ID

        WHERE (act.Code in ('SJM-GTD-HMM-A01','SJM-GTD-HMM-MAN01','SJM-GTD-HMM-PRT01','SJM-GTD-HMM-LAS01'))
        and att.name like ('%Cancel%') 
    ) Cancelled,
    (Select count( emp.ID) 
        FROM [dbo].[factAttempt] fact
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimActivity] act ON act.ID = fact.ActivityID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimUser] emp ON emp.ID = fact.UserID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimDate] dt ON fact.EndDtID = dt.DateID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimCompletionStatus] comp ON fact.CompletionStatusID = comp.ID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimAttendanceStatus] att ON fact.AttendanceStatusID = att.ID

        WHERE (act.Code in ('SJM-GTD-HMM-A01','SJM-GTD-HMM-MAN01','SJM-GTD-HMM-PRT01','SJM-GTD-HMM-LAS01'))
        and att.name like ('%NA%') 
    ) Registered
```

Comment: Looks complicated!  What is you want to know about subqueries?

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the row totals without sub-queries?

Comment: Your desired output with columns "Product name", "type_count", and "User_count" does not match the query you posted with columns of "ActivityName", "Attended", "Inprogress", "Cancelled", and "Registered".  Hard to tell exactly what you're going for since your expected results don't line up with the query, but the issue is likely that your main select for 'ActivityName' should the main query, with each subquery nested inside with the format 'SELECT act.ActivityName, {otherSubqueriesHere} FROM [dbo].[dimActivity] act  WHERE act.Code in ('SJM-GTD-HMM-A01')'.

Comment: What is the primary key on the dimActivity table?  You will need to use that in your subqueries to get the subtotals for each Activity

Comment: @ BateTech - the vendor of the software does not allow sub-queries with their application, thus the problem. The query excutes perfectly and the output is correct in Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: @markeymarc See my modified EDIT to my answer below which does not include subqueries. Seems odd that a vendor would not allow subqueries, but stranger things have happened.  One thing you could also try it to create a database `VIEW` for your query which includes the subqueries, and then select from that view within the app which does not allow subqueries.  Then the app does not know that there is a subquery behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

Your main select for 'ActivityName' should the main query, with each subquery nested inside with the format:

```
SELECT act.ActivityName, {otherSubqueriesGoHere} 
FROM [dbo].[dimActivity] act 
WHERE act.Code in ('SJM-GTD-HMM-A01')
```

Then, within your sub-queries, you can reference values from your main result set in order to filter the sub-query results to only the Activities for the current row.

Here is an example of a modified query.  You will need to change the `and act.ID = actMain.ID` section in each sub-query to use the primary key of your `dimActivity` table instead of `ID`.  I just used `ID` because I don't know what your table structure is.

```
SELECT  
    actMain.ActivityName,
    (   Select count( emp.ID) 
        FROM [dbo].[factAttempt] fact
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimActivity] act ON act.ID = fact.ActivityID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimUser] emp ON emp.ID = fact.UserID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimDate] dt ON fact.EndDtID = dt.DateID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimCompletionStatus] comp ON fact.CompletionStatusID = comp.ID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimAttendanceStatus] att ON fact.AttendanceStatusID = att.ID

        WHERE (act.Code in ('SJM-GTD-HMM-A01','SJM-GTD-HMM-MAN01','SJM-GTD-HMM-PRT01','SJM-GTD-HMM-LAS01'))
        and att.name like ('%Attend%') 
        and act.ID = actMain.ID

    ) Attended,
    (   Select count( emp.ID) 
        FROM [dbo].[factAttempt] fact
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimActivity] act ON act.ID = fact.ActivityID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimUser] emp ON emp.ID = fact.UserID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimDate] dt ON fact.EndDtID = dt.DateID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimCompletionStatus] comp ON fact.CompletionStatusID = comp.ID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimAttendanceStatus] att ON fact.AttendanceStatusID = att.ID

        WHERE (act.Code in ('SJM-GTD-HMM-A01','SJM-GTD-HMM-MAN01','SJM-GTD-HMM-PRT01','SJM-GTD-HMM-LAS01'))
        and att.name like ('%Progress%') 
        and act.ID = actMain.ID
    ) Inprogess,
    (   Select count( emp.ID) 
        FROM [dbo].[factAttempt] fact
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimActivity] act ON act.ID = fact.ActivityID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimUser] emp ON emp.ID = fact.UserID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimDate] dt ON fact.EndDtID = dt.DateID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimCompletionStatus] comp ON fact.CompletionStatusID = comp.ID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimAttendanceStatus] att ON fact.AttendanceStatusID = att.ID

        WHERE (act.Code in ('SJM-GTD-HMM-A01','SJM-GTD-HMM-MAN01','SJM-GTD-HMM-PRT01','SJM-GTD-HMM-LAS01'))
        and att.name like ('%Cancel%') 
        and act.ID = actMain.ID
    ) Cancelled,
    (   Select count( emp.ID) 
        FROM [dbo].[factAttempt] fact
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimActivity] act ON act.ID = fact.ActivityID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimUser] emp ON emp.ID = fact.UserID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimDate] dt ON fact.EndDtID = dt.DateID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimCompletionStatus] comp ON fact.CompletionStatusID = comp.ID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimAttendanceStatus] att ON fact.AttendanceStatusID = att.ID

        WHERE (act.Code in ('SJM-GTD-HMM-A01','SJM-GTD-HMM-MAN01','SJM-GTD-HMM-PRT01','SJM-GTD-HMM-LAS01'))
        and att.name like ('%NA%') 
        and act.ID = actMain.ID
    ) Registered
FROM [dbo].[dimActivity] actMain
WHERE actMain.Code in ('SJM-GTD-HMM-A01')
```

**EDIT:**
I just noticed that each of your sub-queries are basically duplicates with only the comparison of the `att.name` changing, so you could also use a query like this, which includes a group by and sum to count the occurrences of each `att.name` value.

```
SELECT act.ActivityName
    , SUM(case when att.name like ('%Attend%') then 1 else 0 end) as Attended
    , SUM(case when att.name like ('%Progress%') then 1 else 0 end) as Inprogess
    , SUM(case when att.name like ('%Cancel%') then 1 else 0 end) as Cancelled
    , SUM(case when att.name like ('%NA%') then 1 else 0 end) as Registered
FROM [dbo].[factAttempt] fact
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimActivity] act ON act.ID = fact.ActivityID
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimUser] emp ON emp.ID = fact.UserID
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimDate] dt ON fact.EndDtID = dt.DateID
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimCompletionStatus] comp ON fact.CompletionStatusID = comp.ID
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[dimAttendanceStatus] att ON fact.AttendanceStatusID = att.ID
WHERE (act.Code in ('SJM-GTD-HMM-A01','SJM-GTD-HMM-MAN01','SJM-GTD-HMM-PRT01','SJM-GTD-HMM-LAS01'))
GROUP BY act.ActivityName
```

NOTE: this query will not include `ActivityName`s that have a 0 count for all 4 buckets (Attended, Inprogress, Cancelled, Registered).  If you need to include records with all 0's, then you can change the joins to be `LEFT JOIN`s like this:

```
FROM [dbo].[dimActivity] act
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[factAttempt] fact ON act.ID = fact.ActivityID
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[dimUser] emp ON emp.ID = fact.UserID
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[dimDate] dt ON fact.EndDtID = dt.DateID
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[dimCompletionStatus] comp ON fact.CompletionStatusID = comp.ID
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[dimAttendanceStatus] att ON fact.AttendanceStatusID = att.ID
```